# invoke-command works from powershell, does not work from a cmd window invoking powershell

Tags: python, powershell, invoke-command

Hello and happy new year,

I am trying to invoke a command from powershell to a server. To do this, I can write the following lines of codes in a PSS_invoke.ps1 script and call it with `$ 'path/to/PSS_invoke1.ps1'` in a powershell session. It works.
I can also submit each lines of the script to the powershell console and it also works.

```
$session = New-PSSession mycomputer
Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptBlock { start-job -scriptBlock { path\to\stata\stataMP-64.exe -e do path\to\mycommand.do } }
```

Now, let's say that I want to open a cmd window then call a powershell that will invoke command. I do this because I want to run this script from a program that can only call cmd but not powershell.
In a cmd.exe window

```
powershell < "\\path\to\PSS_invoke.ps1"
```

It does not run the command!
I tried the same in Python and I did not get a result either:

```
import subprocess
psInvoke = subprocess.Popen(['powershell',
                             '-ExecutionPolicy',
                             'unrestricted',
                             'path\to\PSS_invoke.ps1',
                             ], cwd=os.getcwd())
result = psInvoke.wait()
```

I did not get any response, neither from Python nor from cmd.
It works when I don't use Invoke-command (and work in local).

I do not have an error message. Just my script does not run.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-File` parameter:

```
powershell -File "\\path\to\PSS_invoke.ps1"
```

If you want to use the script block directly there's also a `-Command` parameter.

You can read about PowerShell.exe arguments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) However these apply to PowerShell 5.1, I don't see a doc for 7.1, but will look around.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your prompt answer. As you suggest, I tried with the following command in cmd:

```
powershell -File "\\path\to\PSS_invoke.ps1"
```

It did not start my stata session. However, I also tried to change the script that launches a simple function.... Which worked... I guess the issue is in the

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName myserver
Invoke-Command -Session $s -scriptBlock { Set-Content -Path 'path*\to\test\test.txt' -Value 'Hello world'}
```

So I imagine the problem is in the `-scriptBlock { start-job -scriptBlock { path\to\stata\stataMP-64.exe -e do path\to\mycommand.do } }`part of the script.